# PHP - Blog Post Commenting System

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

i am having problem to add comments to a blog post system, I've done this using OOP PHP, and here is my code:

```
public function getBlogPosts() {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, posted_by, date_time, title, message FROM blog_posts");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $posted_by, $date_time, $title, $message);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt2 = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, posted_by, date_time, post_id, message FROM blog_comments");
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->bind_result($c_id, $c_posted_by, $c_date_time, $c_post_id, $c_message);
    $stmt2->store_result();
    while($stmt->fetch() && $stmt2->fetch()) {
        echo "<h3>$title</h3>Posted by: $posted_by at $date_time.<br /><br />$message<br />";
        if($stmt2->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt3 = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM blog_comments WHERE post_id=?");
            $stmt3->bind_param('s', $id);
            $stmt3->execute();
            $stmt3->bind_result($n_id);
            $stmt3->store_result();
            if($stmt3->num_rows > 0) {
                while($stmt3->fetch() && $stmt2->fetch()) {
                    echo "<br /><br />" . $c_posted_by . " at " . $c_date_time . "<br />" . $c_message;
                }
            }
            $stmt3->close();
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt2->close();
}
```

In that code, I am trying to get all the blog posts, and get the blog comments to the blog posts if the table 'post_id' matches the id of the blog_posts records. I will be very happy if you can spot out the error, which will help many people who are trying to fix such errors. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any errors or warnings?

Comment: No, I haven't received any errors, but I've done it. My logic was wrong.

Comment: I have done a total re-code of that and it's working fine. I am not giving the code but the logic is

// If there is a blog post then echo the blog post and store the id

// Once you store the id use it to check if there is any blog_comment related to that id and try to link them.

//If there IS an id linked to the blog_comment, then echo it out. Simple? If you have problems, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a total re-code of that and it's working fine. I am not giving the code but the logic is

// If there is a blog post then echo the blog post and store the id

// Once you store the id use it to check if there is any blog_comment related to that id and try to link them.

//If there IS an id linked to the blog_comment, then echo it out. Simple? If you have problems, let me know.